# aligning div content within a div

Tags: html, css, coldfusion

I have a 2 column div left column is a nav bar and right column is page content

in chrome all displays correctly however in ie the content of second column appears as a second column however its displays starting in line with the bottom of the nav bar leaving the height of the nav bar as blank space in the content column

please advise how i can remedy this

```css
#wrapper {
  margin-left: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  background-color: #FFA;
}

#cleared {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  font: 11px 'Trebuchet MS';
  color: #404040;
}

fieldset,
legend {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="sidebar">
    <cfinclude template="navbar.cfm">
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <fieldset>
      <cfinclude template="b2b_add_device.cfm">
        <cfabort>
    </fieldset>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `<cfabort>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can check below snippet for this:

```css
#wrapper {
  position:relative; 
  margin-top:0; 
  top:0;
}
#content {
  margin-left:250px;
  background-color: white;
}
#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #FFA;
}
#cleared {
  clear: both;
}

body {
    font: 11px 'Trebuchet MS';
    color: #404040;
}

fieldset, legend {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="sidebar"><cfinclude template="navbar.cfm"></div>

<div id="content">
<fieldset>
    <cfinclude template="b2b_add_device.cfm"> 
    <cfabort>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: HiI have replaced my code with yours and the problem still exists just as it did with my original code ??? the content div starts to display in the correct column however with blank space above equaling the height of the content of the left column. I am using IE when i have this problem with google chrome my original code works as required. Looking forward to any further advise